# Tfs 2013 - Permission to Prioritize Backlog

Tags: tfs

We have created a TFS Group for our Product Owner, and given that group access to the appropriate Team Project.  We also added the PO's AD account to the Stakeholder Access Level, granting him access to Work.  He appears to be able to do everything that is needed except to prioritize the backlog, which happens to be an important function of the PO.

What permission is required to drag-and-drop (reorder; prioritize) Product Backlog Items in TFS 2013 (Update 4)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your product owner needs a licence.

stakeholder is for.. Well... stakeholders and not product owners. You need an Advanced licence on VSO or a Test Professional licence in TFS.

Once you have the licence you can add them to the Advanced licence container in TFS. Go to the cog and then click the top level in the breadcrumbs. The second tab has the licence levels and Basic will be the default. Add the PO to Advanced.

Comment: He has a license, we just kind of figured the moving the PBI's was part of the normal backlog stuff.  I moved him to the Advanced level, but did not have time to verify if he could prioritize.

Comment: Stakeholder is read only for backlogs and stuff. PO does not want a bunch of stakeholders messing with his order.

Comment: BTW on the screen that you selected Advanced it specifies which features are in which level.